# Associative array align => with PHP-CS-Fixer

Tags: php, php-cs-fixer

Should associative array => should be align with PHP-CS-Fixer ?

```
$array = [
    1    => 'a',
    '1'  => 'b',
    1.5  => 'c',
    true => 'd',
];
```

or

```
$array = [
    1 => 'a',
    '1' => 'b',
    1.5 => 'c',
    true => 'd',
];
```

I didn't find filter for that in https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/PHP-CS-Fixer

Comment: It's an invalid array, you can only use integer or string values as array keys; and a string key containing an integer value wil be silently converted to an integer, so all these will be cast to integer 1 and value `d` will overwrite value `a` for key `1`

Comment: And the answer to your actual question probably depends on the coding standard that you're using

Comment: In fact we don't care about the content, it's just a exemple take from http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For PHP-CS-Fixer v1, it used to be the option: `align_double_arrow`

For newer versions, check the other answer.

Answer (score 11):

This is now a proper way to run the `align_double_arrow` with newer versions of PHP-CS-Fixer (v2, v3), which will align array elements after the double arrow ('=>'):

```
php-cs-fixer fix path \
--rules='{"binary_operator_spaces": {"operators": {"=>": "align_single_space_minimal"}}}'
```

On a configuration file, it would be something like:

```php
'binary_operator_spaces' => [
    'operators' => [
        '=>' => 'align_single_space_minimal',
    ]
]
```

More to read:
https://github.com/PHP-CS-Fixer/PHP-CS-Fixer/blob/master/doc/rules/operator/binary_operator_spaces.rst

Comment: This is the current link: https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/PHP-CS-Fixer/blob/master/doc/rules/operator/binary_operator_spaces.rst